# How to write a while loop that prints from 1 to user_num, increasing by 1 each time?

Tags: python, while-loop

I've tried multiple different ways but all are infinite loops or recursions:

```
i = 1
user_num = int(input())
while user_num > 1:
   print(user_num - (user_num - 1))
```

Sample output with input:

```
4 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: You should print and increment `i`, not `user_num` and stop the loop when `i` is greater than `user_num`.

Comment: Think about what the individual parts of the assignment mean. What does it mean to increase something by `1`? What does it translate to in python? Then ask yourself *what* exactly you want to increase by `1` in each iteration. Then ask yourself what it is that you want to `print` in each iteration. Finally ask yourself under which condition you want to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first method using while loop.

```
i = 1
user_num = int(input())
while i <= user_num:
    print(i)
    i += 1 # incrementation, if not you will have an infinite loop
```

Here's another version using for loop.

```
user_num = int(input())
for i in range(1, (user_num + 1)):
    print(i)
```

> **Input:** 4
>
> **Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `range`

```py
# range(start, stop, step)
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(i)
```

but if keeping it as a while loop is more attractive, try

```py
i =  1
while i < 5:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while i <= user_num:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.